# handling dtype in for loop from an Excel file

Tags: python, selenium-iedriver

I'm trying to extract columns from an excel file onto a website by using pandas for loop.

However, not all data from a specific column have the same data type, so sometimes it can't output due to "datatype" issue and there are even null value in the column.

Is it possible to extract any value regardless of its data type? What does numpy.ndarray actually mean?

[image]

Comment: Please show your full code. `numpy.ndarray` is a multidimensional numpy array, a quick google search will tell you that, [here](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.html).

Comment: As well as a sample data set that reproduces your problem, and any full error message you get, please. As text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

You could use try/except conditionals to catch the various data types.